# Difficulty with component Community Startup tabs (CST) in pentaho CDE

Tags: pentaho, spark-launcher

Please, how do I create a tab with a link?

```
<cstConfig>
  <rule match="USER" pattern="false" value="admin">
    <tab title="Test 001" fullScreen="false" tooltip="A CDF sample">href="google.com"</tab>
  </rule>
</cstConfig>
```

error: Error processing component (tableC)

Or run an existing dashboard in the system (Sparkl App Pentaho)?

---

```
<cstConfig>
  <rule match="USER" pattern="false" value="admin">
    <tab title="Test 001" fullScreen="false" tooltip="A CDF sample">"C:\BI\pentaho-server-ce-8.0.0.0-28\pentaho-server\pentaho-solutions\system\cst\dashboards\launcher.cdfde"</tab>
  </rule>
</cstConfig>
```

error: Error processing component (tableC)

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community startup tab is only for the dashboard, so you must specify CDATA.

The link must be

```
<![CDATA[/pentaho/api/repos/%3Apublic%3Adev%3Asales_report.wcdf/generatedContent]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

its working fine based on user login u can specify cst based on user login .. u can create CST based on user role as well as users

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your attention!

please, can not I call a dashboard with the "cdfde" extension?

<tab title="Sample Sparkl App" fullScreen="false" tooltip="Sparkl App"><![CDATA[/pentaho/plugin/cst/api/launcher]]></tab>      something is missing?

Comment: Hi .. Did u mention extension name . i mean .cda , .wcdf